# Mootools - Targeting child elements with an .each selector

Tags: css-selectors, mootools, targeting

I'm trying to target a UL that's inside a LI and I'm having trouble.  Here's the HTML:

```
<ul id="main_nav">
  <li class="main"><a href="#">Section 1</a>
    <ul id="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="main"><a href="#">Section 2</a>
    <ul id="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="main"><a href="#">Section 3</a></span>
   <ul id="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

and here's the JS:

```
    window.addEvent('load', function() {
    $$('li.main').each(function(el){
    el.getChild('dropdown').addEvent('mouseenter',function(e){
        alert("over!");
    });
    el.getChild('dropdown').addEvent('mouseleave',function(e){
        alert("out!");
    });
});
}
```

I think the problem is when I try to get the child of the LI by using el.getChild('dropdown'), but I don't know any other ways to do this.  I'm not a coder so any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something that may be causing issues are your duplicate ids. An `id` should only be used **once** throughout the page. So, having more than 1 `<ul id="dropdown">` is invalid HTML and may give you unwanted results with libraries.

If you want to keep duplicates, try `name` or `class` attributes.

Now, I'm not sure if it might've changed between releases, but I'm only finding the **plural** [`getChildren`](http://mootools.net/docs/Element/Element#Element:getChildren) in the docs.

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
    $$('li.main').each(function(el){
        el.getChildren('.dropdown').addEvent('mouseenter',function(e){
            alert("over!");
        });
        el.getChildren('.dropdown').addEvent('mouseleave',function(e){
            alert("out!");
        });
    });
});
```

But, then again, I'm not very familiar with Mootools.
As you can probably tell. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the getFirst-method instead of getChild:

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
    $$('li.main').each(function(el){
        el.getFirst().addEvent('mouseenter',function(e){
            alert("over!");
        });
        el.getFirst().addEvent('mouseleave',function(e){
            alert("out!");
        });
    });
});
```